# Initialising const class data member from std::istream in constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, constants

I would like to initialise my class const member in the constructor from std::istream:

```
class MyClass {
   private: const int dataMember;
   public: MyClass(std::istream& is) { /* read into datamember }
}
```

I want to use >> operator of istream instance to fill in my dataMember but my dataMember is const. Is there any way in C++ to do that?

Comment: As others have answered, it is possible. However, I would argue the data member shouldn't be `const`. It's already private and you can enforce that it's `const` to users of `MyClass` via the class API. Also, `const` will break copy semantics (e.g., copy assignment will not work).

Comment: I would like to have pure immutability. For example in newer language such as Scala you may define your class data member as val and you cannot change them even from the class member functions. So once it is created, it can never be changed. That would help a lot in contexts where concurrency matters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, just wrap it in a function:

```
MyClass(std::istream& is) : dataMember{readInt(is)}{}
```

You can handle input errors by throwing from your helper function.

If you *really* want to do it without a helper function, you can force it with an `istream_iterator`:

```
MyClass(std::istream& is) : dataMember{*std::istream_iterator<int>(is)}{}
```

However, this will lead to somewhat wacky error handling. The error handling can be done via [`std::istream::exceptions`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/exceptions), but the caller would have to remember to enable them. Otherwise, a failing read operation will invoke UB.

I prefer the helper function for that error handling reason. (Especially as it took me three iterations to get it right and I advocated UB in one.)

Comment: True, is there any way without introducing a helper function? I generally do not like having lots of small functions to compensate language deficiencies.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function that takes in a stream and returns an object. This function extracts the data from the stream and puts it in the constructor.

```
static MyClass fromIStream(std::istream& is) {
    int datamember;
    is >> datamember;
    return MyClass(datamember);
}
```